# Angular component waiting for service to recive data from API

Tags: angular, promise, angular-services

Hi in my app I have a `service` and a `component'.

My `service` is reciving data from API:

```
getNewShoppingCart() {
  this.serverService.getShoppingCart().subscribe(
    (data) => {
      this.basket.boughtItems = data;
      });
}
```

and my `component` has got some methods that uses the object recived by `service`.

Since the `component` is rendered before the `service` gets the data I have some errors in the console.

How can I force the component to wait until the data is loaded?

Comment: you should check this https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data :)

Comment: you could try to get this data on ngInit() life cycle hook

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **null/ length** check in the component. For example if you are using this object **this.basket.boughtItems** to receive data from service then add ngIf condition in the component like *ngIf="basket.boughtItems.length > 0"

Comment: you have to do a null-check as well, because it's possible that the basket.boughtItems is NULL, so the length-check will cause a nullreference-exception

Answer (score 0):

Make the method to return Observable or use the service directly.

```
getNewShoppingCart(): Observable<ItemsType> {
  return this.serverService.getShoppingCart()
}
```

Create an BehaviorSubject field in the component.

```
shopingCart = new BehaviorSubject();
```

Put some data in it on ngOnInit:

```
shopingCart.next(this.getNewShoppingCart())
```

Use [async](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe in the component point to the shopingCart

Get value form the BehaviorSubject where you need it, like this:

```
shopingCart.getValue()
```